# How to capture exactly the image inside the rectangular overlay in Camera?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I successfully made the auto crop  to some extent for small devices so far. I am facing two issues:
1) the auto crop in big devices lets say 6.5 inches is not working properly 
2) i want to take picture inside the rectangle frame

Below is my code:

```
    public static Bitmap crop(Bitmap originalBitmap) 
    {
    double originalWidth = originalBitmap.getWidth();
    double originalHeight = 
     originalBitmap.getHeight();
    double scaleX = originalWidth / 1280;
      int navBarHeightPxIn1280x720Ui 


     CommonUtils.px2dp(CommonUtils.get 
     NavigationBarHeightInPx()) * 5 ;
    double scaleXMultiplier = ((double) 1280) / 
    ((double) (1280 - navBarHeightPxIn1280x720Ui));
    scaleX = scaleX * scaleXMultiplier;
    double scaleY = originalHeight / 720;
    int x = (int) (52 * scaleX + 0.5);
    int y = (int) (80 * scaleY + 0.5);
    int width = (int) (896 * scaleX + 0.5);
    int height = (int) (588 * scaleY + 0.5);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, x, y, 
     width, height);
     }
```

Comment: *the auto crop in big devices lets say 6.5 inches is not working properly* — what do you mean by that? Out of memory crash?

Comment: @AlexCohn basically my autocrop for small device is working but not up to the mark and when i use it on 6 inches screen device it does not crash but give a wrong output. that means it does not crop perfectly , i really want to crop only the part which comes inside the rectangle frame nothing else